# Swift: How to access CollectionView which is present in ViewController from a Singleton Class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, singleton

I am a iOS Newbie. I have a singleton class in which I am parsing JSON data. At the end, after parsing the data, I am not able reload the CollectionView as it is connected to the ViewController. How do I access the CollectionView present in ViewController class from the Singleton Class, So that I can reload the CollectionView.

Comment: What about `protocol-delegate` method , you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use a completion closure to get a callback when data handling completed.

```
//Singelton
func loadData(onCompletion completion: () -> ()) {
    //load data

    completion()
}

//ViewController 
singeltonInstance.loadData { 
    //reload collectionView
    //collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Additional Info**: If you are loading your data in a background thread you need to call the the completion closure on the main thread.

```
//Singelton
func loadData(onCompletion completion: () -> ()) {
    //load data

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        completion()
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried using your first solution. This way I was able to print the data to the console, but the data did not print on to the collectionView.

Comment: Have you also tried to call the completion closure on the main thread? (see additional info)

Comment: Looks like you never assign the data to your instance variable `arrSurvey`. Try to assign your data array from your singelton in the callback block like `arrSurvey = JSON.arrSurvey` just before you reload your collectionView. Hope this helps.